# How to make Jlabel update and display correctly?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jlabel

I have created a JFrame-popup showing how many items has finish loading.
It worked fine when running in notepad++ (which runs cmd command by plugin), but when using .bat to run it with cmd, JFrame comes out with nothing in it.

```
public class A extends B{

public static void main(String[ ] args) {
    a();
}

protected static void a(){
    //- Frame
    JFrame frame_loading = new JFrame("Loading");
    frame_loading.setSize(250, 100);
    frame_loading.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame_loading.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame_loading.setLocationRelativeTo(null);      // Center in screen

    //- Text
    JLabel label_loading = new JLabel("        Loading... ");
    label_loading.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", 0, 15));
    frame_loading.add(label_loading, BorderLayout.WEST);

    //- Text
    JLabel label_number = new JLabel();
    label_number.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", 0, 15));
    frame_loading.add(label_number, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame_loading.setVisible(true);

    for(...){
        label_number.setText(Integer.toString(i + 1));
    }

  frame_loading.dispose();
  }
}
```

It did somehow works a long time ago in .bat cmd(works once when running the 2nd time), but I never get it to work anymore except using notepad++

I have tired adding ContentPane, JPanel, repaint, pack but no luck.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

//- ContentPane
Container pane = frame_loading.getContentPane();
pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

frame_loading.add(panel);
frame_loading.pack();
```

It should show '   Loading ... (int)',

Comment: Did you want to have a constructor for A? So replace `protected static void A()` with `protected  A()` and invoke by `new A()`

Comment: Sorry for missing code above, now updated. this class A is doing stuff for class B(its father) so I think the 'a' above is constructor? Btw in fact it doesn't even need main in class A, it is just for me to test.

Comment: *How to make Jlabel update and display correctly* Just #setText from EDT.

Comment: " I think the 'a' above is constructor? "  - no, it is a regular static method.

Comment: @c0der I tired your method removing static, and it cause the main interface a bunch of errors, such as adding JPanel twice and other JFrame cannot display on top(even I code it to) so I think I better keep with static.

Comment: please post [mcve]